# Why Remember me is Required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, modelstate

Working on ASP.NET MVC login page. I'm using DevExtreme widgets.
When I enter username/password and click on Login button, controls goes to Login action and I see `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`,

The reason is, ModelState shows error:

> The Remember me? field is required.

I checked my ViewModel and I see it have not tagged the field as required. The weird thing is, when I click on Login button for the second time, it works and ModelState.IsValid is true!!

This is my ViewMode

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Question is, why it is required and why it works on the second click.

This is the code in my view

```
@Html.DevExtreme().CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe).Text(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe).ToString())
```

This is the code in html source

```
<div id="devextreme2"></div>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#devextreme2").dxCheckBox({
            "name": "RememberMe",
            "value": null, 
            "text":"Remember me?",
            "inputAttr": {"id":"RememberMe"}
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The only reason that could be happening is you have an input in your form with `name="RememberMe"` but you have set its value to `null` (or a value other that `true` or `false`) - And a `bool` is always required (it cannot be `null`)

Comment: You are right, the checkbox is initilzied with null, I added constructore to my ViewMode and initialized the field with false, but still in Html I see the initial value is null. that's the problem. thanks for hint

Comment: I'm not psychic :) - show your code.

Comment: I added some code

Comment: I don't know how to initialize a value for it in Razor page

Comment: I'm not familiar with DevExtreme widgets, but I assume the the fact your setting `"value": null,` may be the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161380/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-flicker).

Comment: Yes, that is it. I think I should write some javascript to initialize that. however I don't know why it is setting thevalue to null while my m.RememberMe is set to false!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `bool` property is always required (it cannot be `null` unless its `bool?`).

Unless you specifically set the `.Value()` property of the DevExtreme `CheckBoxFor()` method, it is initialized with `value="null" in the hidden input that is generated by the plugin`. If you do not click on the checkbox, then `null` will be posted and result in `ModelState` being valid.

Assuming you passing an instance of `LoginViewModel` to the view in the GET method, then you can set the default value using

```
@Html.DevExtreme().CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
    .Value(Model.RememberMe)
    .Text(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe).ToString())
```